# Change the geom color in ggplot object returned by H2O function

Tags: r, ggplot2, h2o

The H2O package provides a function to plot shap values per observations. See code below taken from the r documentation.

The function returns a ggplot object but I am not able to change the color of the bars. I am able to add titles, annotations, etc but can't access the geom. I'd like to color the positive values pink and the negative values in blue

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# Import the wine dataset into H2O:
f <- "https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/wine/winequality-redwhite-no-BOM.csv"
df <-  h2o.importFile(f)

# Set the response
response <- "quality"

# Split the dataset into a train and test set:
splits <- h2o.splitFrame(df, ratios = 0.8, seed = 1)
train <- splits[[1]]
test <- splits[[2]]

# Build and train the model:
gbm <- h2o.gbm(y = response,
               training_frame = train)

# Create the SHAP row explanation plot
shap_explain_row_plot <- h2o.shap_explain_row_plot(gbm, test, row_index = 1)
print(shap_explain_row_plot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved like so.

First, inspecting the ggplot object we see that the fill color of the `geom_col` is set as an argument.

```
library(ggplot2)

gg <- shap_explain_row_plot

gg$layers[[1]]
#> geom_col: width = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, fill = #b3ddf2, flipped_aes = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_stack
```

Therefore to map on the `fill` aesthetic we first have to remove the fill argument via

```
gg$layers[[1]]$aes_params$fill <- NULL
```

Second, from the `mapping` we see that the length of the bars corresponds to variable `contribution` which is mapped on the `y` aesthetic.

```
gg$mapping
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `x`    -> `.data$feature`
#> * `y`    -> `.data$contribution`
#> * `text` -> `.data$text`
```

Therefore, to get your desired result you could map `contribution < 0` on the fill aesthetic and set the desired color values via `scale_fill_manual`

```
gg + aes(fill = contribution < 0) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "blue", "FALSE" = "pink"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you